# How do you include Templated Web pages into ruby on rails app without changing anything on those pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For an instance, I have these folder containing those HTML files (with different pages), on the other hand, I have this ruby on rails app. How to include the folder with HTML files inside our ruby on rails app?

And How to add functionalities on buttons without touching the codes on HTMLs

Comment: those are static HTML pages?

Comment: Yes. Static Pages but I was asked not to touch anything on the frontend part. I was just asked to add functionalities on the backend part and not to touch anything on the frontend part. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

create a controller to handle static HTML pages

```
rails g controller static
```

make it like

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render params[:page]
  end
end
```

move the static html pages inside views/static/ directory

add the following line to routes.rb file

```
get '/:page' => 'static#show', as: 'static_page'
```

create an link to static about page 'about.html'

```
<%= link_to 'About', static_page_path('about') %>
```

Comment: Where do I paste the existing web folder inside the ruby on rails app?

Comment: Also, The existing webApp has multiple pages, how do I display them all?

Comment: `And How to add functionalities on buttons without touching the codes on HTML` you can't, you need to add rails helper tags for the button to add functionalities, also can you share more details so it will be easy to answer that what pages you want to display?